# i can't get the scroll bottom bar out requested by facebook like iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: bottom scroll bar is a problem]

It is a problem that I can't seem to work throught, when I inspect elements they are all in order for the scroll bar to not be present still it is present, idon't know how to inspect this problem, first I suspected that there might be an iframe problem or a table that is bigger than the container. Please help me with suggestions on how to discover this problem.
I worked [here](http://mediatec.speedsites.ro/consumabile-pentru-imprimanta/cartuse-inkjet-compatibile/cartus-inkjet-negru-compatibil-cu-bci-24bk-bpi-424bk.html)

It may be a problem of jQuery, also.

I tested it on both Chrome and Firefox, in Chrome appears to be just right.

I've dettected the source to be the facebook like . :( But i still don't know how it manages to affect the current window or how to stop it. I also dettected an attribute: `overflow: visible`, on `<div id="fb-root">`

Comment: I suggest you include a screen shot of the issue to give everyone a better idea of what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `overflow-x:hidden;` on your body tag (just tried quickly using firebug and seems to work on firefox 3.6.19).

Answer (score 1):

try "web developer" for firefox. it will give you the correct information about the elements.

I just do not see the bug, so I'll suggest you to delete your cache.
in Firefox -> ctrl+shift+del

All browsers has this function, just have to find it.

Comment: I don't want to scroll anything, i just want the scroll out, but i also cannot detect it's source if it is on div, iframe or something else :(

Comment: I sow on your image some kind of logo on the right, maybe it is the problem. I do not see it on my browser (latest firefox). Maybe it's a typo in the code. Try html validator.

Comment: that logo is feedly add-on but it does has no infuence over the bar

Comment: did you try locating the problem with "web developer" for firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript on your page is causing the problem. Try disabling javascript and you will see. Maybe the body onload function is causing this.